# passing Object Instances as generics to a method

Tags: java, generics

I have a scenario similar to the below example.

I have two different objects and have already created instances from them. I need to pass these instances as generic to a method parameters.

I tried passing the method parameters as Class obj but it didnt work

```
Class A
{

A()
{
List<String>collection = new ArrayList<>();
}

}

Class B
{

B()
{
List<String>collection = new ArrayList<>();
}

}

Class Main()
{

A a = new A(); 
B b = new B();

methodTest(a);
methodTest(b);

void methodTest(Class<T> genericObj)
{
 genericObj.collection.add("1");
 // I need to pass both the instance A and instance B to 
 genericObj


}


}
```

Need some suggestions.

Comment: Show us what you have attempted

Comment: There will not be any efficient or convenient way to do what you're trying to do.  You can't really generify over classes like this without a common interface.

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass generics to methods, since generic is a Type, not an object.

What you do is, you pass an object; with generic being declared in your class.

E.g.

```
public class Test <T extends ClasThatHasCollection> {

    void methodTest(T genericObj) {
        genericObj.collection.add("1"); 
    }
}
```

However in your case, generics seem like an overkill!

Just have a parent class P that has .collection instance variable; and have both classes A and B extend P; and pass object type P into methodTest:

```
public class P {
    public Collection collection;
    // ....
}

public class A extends P {

}

void methodTest(P genericObj) {
     P.collection.add("1");
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the collection to the parent class. Is there any other approach?

Comment: What can be improved in this answer to fix it?

Comment: @srinathbalasuramanian Why didn't you include those requirements in your post? How is anyone supposed to provide a valid answer if you keep changing the requirements?

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to create a base class and have A and B inherit from it.
In the method you use the base class as the type.
This is valid since both A and B extend it.

For example:

```
class Base {
   List<String> collection;
   Base() {
    collection = new ArrayList<>();
   }
} 

class A extends Base{
    A(){
       super()
    }
}

class B extend Base{
    B(){
       super()
    }
}

void methodTest(Base genericObj)
{
   genericObj.collection.add("1");
}
```

Another possibility is to use an interface. This would be useful if the collections are not the same type and are therefore not defined in the base object.

Using an interface:

```
interface MyInterface{
  public ArrayList<> getCollection();
}

class A implements MyInterface {

   List<String> collection;
    A(){
    collection = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    public ArrayList<> getCollection(){
        return collection;
    }
}

class B implements MyInterface{
   List<String> collection;
    B(){
       collection = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ArrayList<> getCollection(){
        return collection;
    }
}



void methodTest(MyInterface genericObj)
{
   genericObj.getCollection().add("1");
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the collection to the base class. Is there any other approach?

Comment: @srinathbalasuramanian Why can't you change it to the base class? It will not be the same instance. You will get a different one for A and B.

Comment: I don't have the control to make any changes to base class. I have only access to change on mine

Comment: @srinathbalasuramanian Did you downvote the answers we both gave? That's not what downvote is for

Comment: @theblitz - technically, unlikely. You need 125 rep points to downvote, which the OP does not have. :)

Comment: Okay. Sorry for the accusation.